# What technology to choose ? Spring Batch or Hadoop?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-batch

I need to process 300 GB log files per day (<kbd>Import</kbd> -> <kbd>Convert to other format</kbd> -> <kbd>Upload</kbd>).

Which is the best technology to choose? **Spring Batch** or **Apache Hadoop**? I am very new to these technologies and could not trace there limitations. Moreover, the file size may grow day by day unlimited. Apart from this, I need to design the application with given hardware 3 Sun Blade Servers with Disaster Recovery method. Please suggest.

Comment: can you be more specific about the "convert" part of your application? Both spring batch and hadoop support parallel processing but to decide which one to use, you need to analyze your requirements and the intricacies of each platform

Comment: At present the processing is minimal. Eg: The original log file contains key & value (Subscriber Number=+91 90090090), comma seperate values. Now I need to alter the key name with another key name defined by the vendor. Eg: Subscriber Number=MSISDN, so the final would be MSISDN=+91 90090090.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a mere file format conversion, there is no point in using Hadoop, unless you can break the file into chuncks that can be distributed in an embarassingly parallel manner.

Additionally, if you do not need to store / index / process these information any further, there is no need to keep it stored somewhere.

Last but not least, do evaluate the cost of breaking the file into units as part of the overall computational cost.

Comment: I have three sun blade server. Can I make one as Master & other one as Slave ? I have one more remaining. How could I handle disaster recovery with this.

Comment: Technically speaking, yes. This document is very exhaustive: http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/SBP/Spring+Batch+PU